# Creating a stored procedures from code - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem with creating a stored procedures in a SQL Server database. This is what I would do :

```
public void selectMeetings(String PID)
{
    String connection = "Server=localhost;Database=master;Integrated security=true;";
    SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection();

    Connection = new SqlConnection(connection);
    Connection.Open();

    string script = "USE ["+PID+ "] GO CREATE PROCEDURE selectMeetings AS SELECT * FROM dbo.MEETING GO";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(script, Connection);

    try
    {
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The problem is this:

> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch

I tried to remove GO but the problem is :

> 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query
>   batch.

How to solve this ? Thanks

Comment: `GO` is batch separator, not T-SQL. Set connection string to default catalog and delete `USE`. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212077/the-proper-use-of-mssql-go-in-vba/32212122#32212122)

Comment: exactly , so how can I fix to make a Transact ?

Comment: You need to separate this from what you're coding....try it in SSMS and get it right there first, then bring it back and fit it into your code accordingly.

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE selectMeetings AS BEGIN SELECT * FROM dbo.MEETING END` and add `;Initial Catalog=<your_DB>`  to connection string

Comment: That code you see is taken from SQL Server 2014 in the creation of Stored Procedures Panel

Comment: @Mr.Developer doesn't mater at all. *That* script was generated for use by SSMS or sqlcmd, which *do* recognize these batch commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch the database from your [client code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.changedatabase(v=vs.110).aspx) and, as others have said, don't send `GO` since it's *not* a T-SQL command:

```
public void selectMeetings(String PID)
{
    String connection = "Server=localhost;Database=master;Integrated security=true;";
    SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection();

    Connection = new SqlConnection(connection);
    Connection.Open();

    Connection.ChangeDatabase(PID);

    string script = "CREATE PROCEDURE selectMeetings AS SELECT * FROM dbo.MEETING";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(script, Connection);

    //You're not fishing. There's no point in catch and release
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Further fixes for best practice:

```
public void selectMeetings(String PID)
{
    String connection = "Server=localhost;Database=master;Integrated security=true;";
    using(SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
      Connection.Open();

      Connection.ChangeDatabase(PID);

      string script = "CREATE PROCEDURE selectMeetings AS SELECT * FROM dbo.MEETING";
      using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(script, Connection))
      {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't connection be closed after execution?

Comment: I closed the connection , it works! thank you. Now I put the answer is right .

Comment: @Mr.Developer - ideally, you wrap all of your use of `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects in `using` statements so that they're automatically cleaned. I was mostly trying to address the immediate issues.